# How are state flags represented and how bitwise OR is used to work with bit flags?

Tags: c++, fstream

If we open a file for reading, we may define one or more state flags,
for example: `ios::out` as well as `ios::out | iso::app`

I read about the bitwise OR, and how it "merges" the two bit sets,

for example: 1010 | 0111 = 1111

now that being said, I do not understand how it works "behind the scenes" when we use a method like `ifstream.open(filename, stateflagA | stateflagB | stateflagC)` and so on.

Can someone elaborate more on the inner workings of these state flags and their memory representation?

EDIT:
To give more emphasis on what i am trying to understand (if it helps),
I would assume that the open method could receive one or more state flags as separate arguments in the signature, and not delimited by a bitwise OR, so i want to understand how the bitwise OR works on these state flags to produce a different final state when combining several flags, and as a result allows me to use only one argument for a state flag or a set of state flags.
ie:

```
ifstream.open(filename, stateflagA | stateflagB | stateflagC)
```

and NOT

```
ifstream.open(filename, stateflagA , stateflagB , stateflagC)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "behind the scenes"?

Comment: what i mean is - lets say i enable two flags ios::out | ios::app, in what way will it be different than setting 3 flags separated by bitwise or? does that also mean there is a limit to how many flags i can set? can an example be given in binary?

to be honest. i think i may really simply understand it if i knew how each of these state flags is represented in memory, how big they are and what is their binary value etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take the GNU libstdc++ implementation and look at how these are actually implemented, we find:

```
enum _Ios_Openmode 
{ 
  _S_app        = 1L << 0,
  _S_ate        = 1L << 1,
  _S_bin        = 1L << 2,
  _S_in         = 1L << 3,
  _S_out        = 1L << 4,
  _S_trunc      = 1L << 5,
  _S_ios_openmode_end = 1L << 16 
};
```

These values are then used as this:

```
typedef _Ios_Openmode openmode;

static const openmode app =     _S_app;

/// Open and seek to end immediately after opening.
static const openmode ate =     _S_ate;

/// Perform input and output in binary mode (as opposed to text mode).
/// This is probably not what you think it is; see
/// http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt11ch27s02.html
static const openmode binary =  _S_bin;

/// Open for input.  Default for @c ifstream and fstream.
static const openmode in =      _S_in;

/// Open for output.  Default for @c ofstream and fstream.
static const openmode out =     _S_out;

/// Open for input.  Default for @c ofstream.
static const openmode trunc =   _S_trunc;
```

Since the values are chosen as `1 << n`, they are exactly one "bit" each, which allows us to combine then using `|` (or) - as well as other similar operations.

So `app` in binary is `0000 0001` and `bin` is `0000 0100`, so if we do `app | bin` as a mode for opening the file, we get `0000 0101`. The internals of the impplementation of `fstream` can then use

```
 if (mode & bin) ... do stuff for binary file ...
```

and

```
 if (mode & app) ... do stuff for appending to the file ...
```

Other C++ library implementations may choose a different set of bit values for each flag, but will use a similar system.

Answer (score 7):

Bit flags are represented in the same exact way all integral values are represented. What makes them "flags" is your program's *interpretation* of their values.

Bit flags are used for compact representation of small sets of values. Each value is assigned a bit index. All integer numbers with the bit at that index set to `1` are interpreted as sets that include the corresponding member.

Consider a small example: let's say we need to represent a set of three colors - red, green, and blue. We assign red an index of zero, green and index of 1, and blue an index of two. This corresponds to the following representation:

```
BINARY DECIMAL COLOR
------ ------- -----
   001       1  Red
   010       2  Green
   100       4  Blue
```

Note that each flag is a power of two. That's the property of binary numbers that have a single bit set to `1`. Here is how it would look in C++:

```
enum Color {
    Red   = 1 << 0
,   Green = 1 << 1
,   Blue  = 1 << 2
};
```

`1 << n` is the standard way of constructing an integer with a single bit at position `n` set to `1`.

With this representation in hand we can construct sets that have any combination of these colors:

```
BINARY DECIMAL COLOR
------ ------- -----
   001       1  Red
   010       2  Green
   011       3  Red+Green
   100       4  Blue
   101       5  Blue+Red
   110       6  Blue+Green
   111       7  Blue+Green+Red
```

Here is when bit operations come into play: we can use them to construct sets and check membership in a single operation.

For example, we can construct a set of `Red` and `Blue` with an `|` like this:

```
Color purple = Red | Blue;
```

Behind the scenes, all this does is assigning `5` to `purple`, because `4 | 1` is `5`. But since your program interprets `5` as a set of two colors, the meaning of that `5` is not the same as that of an integer `5` that represents, say, the number of things in a bag.

You can check if a set has a particular member by applying `&` to it:

```
if (purple & Red) {
    // returns true
}
if (purple & Green) {
    // returns false
}
```

The flags used by I/O library work in the same way. Some of the flags are combined to produce *bit masks*. They work in the same way as individual flags, but instead of letting you find membership they let you find set intersection in a single bit operation:

```
Color yellow = Blue | Green;
Color purple = Red | Blue;
Color common = yellow & purple; // common == Blue
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time and effort to answer this :) it does help

Answer (score 2):

"Behind the scene", in the memory of the computer every information is ultimately coded as a group of bits. Your CPU is wired to perform basic [binary algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) operations (AND, OR, XOR, NOT) on such elementary information.

C++ operators `|` `&` and `^` just give direct access to these CPU operations on any integral types.  For flag management it's wise to use an unsigned integral type such as `unsigned int` or `unsigned char`.

An express overview:

- the trick is that every flag corresponds to a fixed bit.  This is usually done with a power of 2 constant (ex: 1,2,4,8 which are binary coded as 0001,0010, 0100 and 1000).
- constants are named because it's clearer than using litterals (ex:  `const unsigned FlagA=1, FlagB=2, FlagC=4;`)
- binary AND `x & y` ensures that only bits that are 1 in both x and y remain 1.  So this is used to reset flags by "anding" with a value where the flag is 0.  So `x & FlagB` reset all flags exept flag B
- binary OR `x | y` any bits that are 1 either in x or y become 1.  So it's used to set flags.  Example:  `x | FlagB` sets the flag B.
- a binary AND is also a quick way to check if a flag is set:  `(x & FlagB)` will be true if and only if the flag B was set.

**EDIT:** About your specific question on [`ifstream::open()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/) parameters: it's a design choice, for convenience.  As you can see there are 6 flags that influence the way the file is handled (some of them being used very rarely).  So instead of providing each of the 6 flags every time, the standard decide that you'd provide them combined in an openmode.  Variable number of arguments would not have been an alternative, as the called function would have to know how many arguments you've provided.

Comment: can you please expand with an example of two or more state flags? 
how is a state flag represented in memory? how many bits, and how the combination of several state flags gives me a different state result on the bit level

Comment: @SwiftHands in general a state flag is represented as one bit.  If you combine several flags, you have several bits.  Example:  `FlagA|FlagB` above would be  `0001|0010` which is `0011`